# Email address verification

Tags: email, api, smtp

We currently have front desk staff collecting client email addresses which leads to more than a few typos, and obviously even if one character is off, the entire address is off. Are there any tools/utilities/APIs that offer address verification? We've looked at a couple, for example mxtoolbox offers this in their full "Delivery Center" solution, but it's a bit pricey for the low volume we'd have. Currently we're just doing some basic error checking of addresses to catch the more egregious ones (i.e. "gmai.com" or "yaho.com") but we have many clients with school district addresses which are more complex and extremely difficult to sniff out without the help of some sort of validation tool. (suggestions that only do domain verification (and not specific mailbox) are also welcome)

Comment: Why is "gmai" not a proper domain? Or let me ask you "Why couldn't it be a proper domain even if you somehow determined today that it doesn't exist yet? This is the nature of the problem you face and there is no solution for it. Are you asking the question: "How can we block clients that don't have addresses in the following <include list> domains?

Comment: When staff collect client signatures for later use, because of COVID, it's usually over the phone, and there are many mistakes when they enter them. We want to be able to run email addresses through a verification tool of some sort (like mxtoolbox offers) which will baiscally say "Yes, user@domain.com is a valid address" and if not, we can check it and reach back out to the client to get the correct address. The "gmai" example is just a crude example of what we're looking for manually and having staff correct if they exist. A tool like mxtoolbox checks or "pings" it (for lack of a better term)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I suggest you add your very useful comment, or the information therein, to the question itself  and delete the comment.

Comment: To validate an email address, the usual solution is to send an email to it with a click-through back to your validation mechanism. If your support staff struggle to confirm addresses by standard vocal means - "A for alpha, B for bravo" etc, as internationally recognised, then no validation method is going to be effective. Typos cannot be validated. Your staff need better training. [Case in point recently… someone trying to phonetically spell something actually said "M for Movember" after the charity supported by growing moustaches in November. Chaos, as you can imagine.

Comment: How are you collecting email addresses? In an electronic database system? Or perhaps in a text file? Is it possible to produce a file containing just the names of recipients associated with their email addresses?